# Calling Dynamic Blocks

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to use a captured columnview block as a variable for another source block. The Block of which looks like this:

```
#+Name: Room-Table
#+BEGIN: columnview :skip-empty-rows t   
|Big ol table|
#+END:
```

I checked that the table properly exports, which it does. However if I try to use the data in that table like so:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var t=Room-Table
t
#+END_SRC
```

I get an error that reads:

```
Reference not found
```

This is a different error than if you try to use a variable that doesn't appear in the buffer.

I've tried a few things, like tangling the block out, which doesn't work or calling it the the #+CALL: header which doesn't seem to do anything either.

Finally I looked online, however the only documentation on Dynamic blocks is very sparse, and lacking anything besides setting them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :skip-empty-rows t
#+Name: Room-Table   
|Big ol table|
#+END:
```

You just have to have the name inside the dynamic block.